# Shared entities between an intranet backend and a fronted in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm working in an Symfony2 application. I want the back-end to be only available from the intranet and the front-end available to the public. The Doctrine entities are shared by both.

What would be the best approach to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best approach would be to use FOSUserBundle ( https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle ) and to determine for your backend which roles have granted access to your backend.

for exemple  :

```
frontend : no role defined
intranet : only registred user -> ROLE_USER 
backend : only registred user with admin access -> ROLE_ADMIN
```

it's very easy to deploy since symfony2 documentation talks about it

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

and a very good admin generator for sf2 : 
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle

hope this will help

Comment: and to fully answers your question, your entities are parts of the same application, so yes they re both shared between all parts ( backend , frontend, intranet, etc. ) but only granted roles would be able to use it ) :)